# Second book on QFT before understanding Conformal Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, education

I'm a newcomer to Quatum Field Theory, recently I started to work with the very basic book of [Lancaster](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199699321). My final destination is to learn Conformal Field Theory applied to Quantum Phase Transitions and Condesed matter.

What would be a second book in QFT towards this aim? I ask this because many of them are oriented towards high energy and particles, which I'm not sure I will need all of those topics.

Finally, I would like to say that I have [Altland's](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=alexander+altland%2C+ben+d.+simons%2C+condensed+matter+field+theory&crid=3QR5LQMRDMOV4&sprefix=simon+altlan%2Caps%2C207&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_12) book, but it's not well suitable for self-studying since it has a lot of typos.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think you missed the aim of the question. I will rephrase it, please mark it as a valid one.

Comment: Note that res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE. You probably have to write out clearly in the title what you want and how it is different, or else the Phys.SE community will not notice the difference.

Comment: I changed the title also. I just want recommendation for a second book with aim to condensed matter. Or someone who can tell me from the standard books which is the most topics needed.

Comment: With your goals you will probably need a better understanding of renormalization group than is usually provided in particle physics-oriented textbooks, so be aware of that.